# Java Lambda method reference not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, java-8, method-reference

My original code is this:

```
private static void onClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    // code to execute
}

// somewhere else in the program:
setOnMouseClicked(event -> SomeClass.onClicked(event));
```

But IntelliJ says "Can be replaced with method reference" which I'm not too sure how to do. I thought I would do this:

```
setOnMouseClicked(event -> SomeClass::onClicked);
```

But then that tells me "void is not a functional interface", but I don't want to return anything. I just want the handler to execute. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are mixing a lambda expression with a method reference.

Change

```
setOnMouseClicked(event -> SomeClass::onClicked);
```

to

```
setOnMouseClicked(SomeClass::onClicked);
```

Comment: @Mayron FIY, IntelliJ can change a lambda expression with method reference for you (when it is possible). Just use alt+enter shortcut on expression

Comment: @Prim Thanks, just tried it out. Very useful to know!